# How can I do to find in xml with bitwise-and with xpath and java?

Tags: java, xml, xpath, bitwise-operators, bitwise-and

I have this [sample xml](https://docs.google.com/leaf?id=0B0jZoSAZwtsiNGY1N2E0YTEtOWNiZi00NDA1LTk1ODQtYTE3ZDBiZjAxZDI1&hl=es).

Each row has an id field, it has values as bits.

And I want to find in this file with bitwise-and operator but I don't know if this is possible.

I read about the operator '&' in javascript or comand BITAND in Oracle but nothing in xml o xpath.

This is the example code in java and xpath:

```
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory;
import javax.xml.xpath.XPath;
import javax.xml.xpath.XPathConstants;

import javax.xml.xpath.XPathFactory;

import org.w3c.dom.Document;
import org.w3c.dom.Element;
import org.w3c.dom.Node;
import org.w3c.dom.NodeList;

public class Util implements java.io.Serializable  {

    static public String filter_xpath_bitand (int var_tipo)

        NodeList nodeList = null;
        Element  element  = null;
        try {
            XPath xpath = XPathFactory.newInstance().newXPath();
            DocumentBuilderFactory factory  = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
            DocumentBuilder        builder  = factory.newDocumentBuilder();
            Document            document = builder.parse(new File(fileXML));      
           nodeList = (NodeList)xpath.evaluate("/test/row[(id & \""+ var_tipo +"\") > 1]", document.getDocumentElement(), XPathConstants.NODESET);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("*** filterXML --> exception: " + e.toString());
        }

    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

From looking at the XPATH reference there is no such thing as bitwise operations.

You could work around that though by making use of existing operations (mod etc).

See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1106044/701884) for a related question.

**EDIT:**

Sample xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<test>
    <row>
        <id>32</id>
        <titulo>yellow</titulo>
    </row>
    <row>
        <id>16</id>
        <titulo>green</titulo>
    </row>
    <row>
        <id>8</id>
        <titulo>red</titulo>
    </row>
    <row>
        <id>1</id>
        <titulo>blue</titulo>
    </row>
    <row>
        <id>2</id>
        <titulo>white</titulo>
    </row>
    <row>
        <id>4</id>
        <titulo>black</titulo>
    </row>
</test>
```

Java code:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;

import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory;
import javax.xml.xpath.XPath;
import javax.xml.xpath.XPathConstants;

import javax.xml.xpath.XPathFactory;

import org.w3c.dom.Document;
import org.w3c.dom.Node;
import org.w3c.dom.NodeList;

public class BitWiseXPathTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Set<String> selectedColors = new HashSet<String>();
        int var_tipo = 33;
        try {
            XPath xpath = XPathFactory.newInstance().newXPath();
            DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory
                    .newInstance();
            DocumentBuilder builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();
            String fileXML = "bitwise.xml";
            Document document = builder.parse(new File(fileXML));

            String evalStr = "/test/row/id";
            NodeList nodeList = (NodeList)xpath.evaluate(evalStr, document.getDocumentElement(), XPathConstants.NODESET);

            for (int i = 0; i < nodeList.getLength(); i++) {
                Node aNode = nodeList.item(i);
                if( (Integer.parseInt(aNode.getTextContent()) & var_tipo) > 0) {
                    //System.out.println("color: "+aNode.getNextSibling().getNextSibling().getTextContent());
                    selectedColors.add(aNode.getNextSibling().getNextSibling().getTextContent());
                }
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("*** filterXML --> exception: " + e.toString());
        }

        System.out.println(selectedColors);

    }

}
```

Again, XPATH doesn't seem to have a bitwise operation. You could move the operation outside of XPATH and do it in Java as a workaround.

Comment: I've reviewed the link but it isnt' usefull because I want to find without xsl.

Comment: I understand the workaorund but the real xml has 52.000 items and it's very slow each query. I don't believe that it's not possible by xpath.

Comment: And XPATH is your only possibility? An XML that large seems to be better of being parsed by SAX.

Comment: Perhaps but I don't know so how could I find by SAX with BITAND ¿?

Comment: It comes down to using the bitwise operators in Java if that's within your range of options. It's just that XML's this large are more performance-wise better handled by SAX than DOM.