# How to use bitwise or in xslt?

Tags: xml, xslt

I have the following code that contains 3 variables which values depend on an xml.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" 
            xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
            xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
            xmlns:date="java.util.Date"                
            xmlns:vector="java.util.Vector"                
            xmlns:math="java.lang.Math"
            xmlns:int="java.lang.Integer"
            xmlns:saxon="http://saxon.sf.net/"
            extension-element-prefixes="date vector math int saxon">
    <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:variable name="var1">
    code to generate the value
</xsl:variable>
<xsl:variable name="var2">
    code to generate the value
</xsl:variable>
<xsl:variable name="var3">
    code to generate the value
</xsl:variable>
```

The problem is that I have to combine this values for another variable:

```
<xsl:variable name="var4">
    value = var1 | var2 | var3
</xsl:variable>
```

Is there an elegant way of doing this?
I have already looked at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1106044/xslt-bitwise-logic) answer but I did not find it useful.

The only solution that comes to my mind is

1. Transform the numbers into strings containing their binary representation
2. Take 2 strings and compare each letter and hold the result
3. Take the result and compare it with the last string
4. Transform the binary representation back to integer

Comment: What kind of values do your variables hold? Which version of Saxon do you use? Have you checked whether you can make use of a Java extension function to perform the bitwise operation on numbers?

Comment: The variables hold 8bit values, I don't know where to check the Saxon version and I don't know how to use a Java extension function.

Comment: Can you show us the code that defines a variable value? Or at least tell us which type the variable has in the XSLT/XPath type system. As for checking the Saxon version, if you run Saxon from the command line then use the `-t` option, it will output details like `Saxon-PE 9.6.0.1J from Saxonica`.

Comment: it looks like this `<xsl:value-of select="($ossol//CPUClk[@Fclk = $CPUclock]/../@PLLDIV) *(math:pow(2,4))"/>` 

I had documented a bit more and I was wandering if I could use Java.math.BigInteger

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use a commercial edition of Saxon 9 then you can call into Java and use the `BigInteger` class. Here is an example meant to be used with Saxon 9.6 PE or EE making use of that class and of XSLT 3.0 to implement bitwise `or` and `and` for two `xs:integer` values and for sequences of `xs:integer` values:

```
<xsl:stylesheet
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
  xmlns:math="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions/math"
  xmlns:bigint="java:java.math.BigInteger"
  xmlns:mf="http://example.com/mf"
  exclude-result-prefixes="xs math bigint mf"
  version="3.0">

<xsl:param name="integer-seq1" as="xs:integer*" select="1, 2, 4, 16"/>

<xsl:function name="mf:or" as="xs:integer">
  <xsl:param name="i1" as="xs:integer"/>
  <xsl:param name="i2" as="xs:integer"/>
  <xsl:sequence select="bigint:or(bigint:new(string($i1)), bigint:new(string($i2)))"/>
</xsl:function>

<xsl:function name="mf:or" as="xs:integer">
  <xsl:param name="integers" as="xs:integer+"/>
  <xsl:sequence select="fold-left(
                          $integers[position() gt 1],
                          $integers[1],
                          mf:or#2
                        )"/>
</xsl:function>

<xsl:function name="mf:and" as="xs:integer">
  <xsl:param name="i1" as="xs:integer"/>
  <xsl:param name="i2" as="xs:integer"/>
  <xsl:sequence select="bigint:and(bigint:new(string($i1)), bigint:new(string($i2)))"/>
</xsl:function>

<xsl:function name="mf:and" as="xs:integer">
  <xsl:param name="integers" as="xs:integer+"/>
  <xsl:sequence select="fold-left(
                          $integers[position() gt 1],
                          $integers[1],
                          mf:and#2
                        )"/>
</xsl:function>


<xsl:template name="main">
  <xsl:value-of select="mf:or(1, 16), mf:and(1, 16), mf:or($integer-seq1), mf:and($integer-seq1), '&#10;'"/>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

With earlier versions of Saxon you can't use the `fold-left` based solution for sequences but the two argument versions should work. As `math:pow` returns an `xs:double`, you would need to cast to an integer first before trying to use the functions.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help! I get an error at the `#` character but I thing can manage with `<xsl:value-of select="bigint:or(bigint:new(string($Var1)), bigint:new(string($Var2)))"/>` .

Comment: As I said, the function definitions using `fold-left` (and that function reference `mf:or#2`) are XSLT/XPath 3.0 only supported by Saxon 9.6 PE or EE.

Answer (score 4):

Here's a **XSLT 1.0** implementation of bitwise OR on decimal parameters, using a recursive template:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:variable name="n" select="49" />
<xsl:variable name="m" select="50" />

<xsl:template match="/">
    <output>
        <xsl:call-template name="bitwise-or">
            <xsl:with-param name="n" select="$n"/>
            <xsl:with-param name="m" select="$m"/>
        </xsl:call-template>
    </output>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template name="bitwise-or">
    <xsl:param name="n"/>
    <xsl:param name="m"/>
    <xsl:param name="power" select="1"/>
    <xsl:param name="value" select="0"/>

    <xsl:variable name="bit" select="$n mod 2 or $m mod 2"/>
    <xsl:variable name="nextN" select="floor($n div 2)"/>
    <xsl:variable name="nextM" select="floor($m div 2)"/>
    <xsl:variable name="result" select="$value  + $bit * $power"/>

    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="$nextN or $nextM">
            <xsl:call-template name="bitwise-or">
                <xsl:with-param name="n" select="$nextN"/>
                <xsl:with-param name="m" select="$nextM"/>
                <xsl:with-param name="power" select="2 * $power"/>
                <xsl:with-param name="value" select="$result"/>
            </xsl:call-template>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
            <xsl:value-of select="$result" />
        </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The **result** of the given example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<output>51</output>
```

Comment: Thank you for your help but it is much safer and easier to use a java method.

Comment: @AlexandruCimpanu Safer?

Answer (score 0):

Saxon 9.6 (PE or higher) implements the EXPath Binary module

http://expath.org/spec/binary

This provides operations such as bin:or, bin:and, bin:xor on Base64Binary values, as well as operations such as bin:pack-integer which converts an integer to a Base64Binary value.