# XSLT: convert wildcard-mask to netmask & format of netmask

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

I have an XML input with this structure:

```
<address>
    <ip>192.168.7.5</ip>
    <netmask>16</netmask>
    <wildcard-mask>0.0.0.255</wildcard-mask>
    <enable-wildcard-mask>false</enable-wildcard-mask>
</address>
```

I want to create a XSLT transformation that takes this input and uses either the 
 'wildcard-mask' value if 'enable-wildcard-mask' is true, or the 'netmask' value if 'enable-wildcard-mask' is false.
However, the netmask must be converted from this format "24" to "255.255.255.0" and the wildcard mask must be converted to a netmask (binary negated).

So the output of this XSLT should be something like:

```
<netmask>255.255.255.0</netmask>
```

if 'enable-wildcard-mask' is true, and

```
<netmask>255.255.0.0</netmask>
```

if 'enable-wildcard-mask' is false.

This is the skeleton XSLT code for testing:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:template match="address">
    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="wildcard-mask and (enable-wildcard-mask/text()='true')">
            <netmask type="string"><xsl:value-of select="wildcard-mask"/></netmask>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:when test="netmask">
            <netmask type="string"><xsl:value-of select="netmask"/></netmask>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

How do I do the necessary bit-wise transformations in XSLT?

Comment: Here is already a question about bitwise logic: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1106044/xslt-bitwise-logic

Comment: More recently, the EXPath Binary module has become available, providing a library of functions for manipulating binary data. It is available in products that are being actively developed such as Saxon, but not of course in older XSLT 1.0 processors.

Answer (score 0):

In the end I implemented the transformations using look-up tables, since there are only 32 entries for each.

Therefore the first look-up table converts a wildcard mask to a netmask, and the 2nd one converts a netmask in this form "/24" to this form 255.255.255.0.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:template match="address">
    <xsl:choose>
        <!-- These 2 look-up tables convert a wildcard to a netmask, and a netmask in this form '/24' to '255.255.255.0', respectively -->
        <xsl:when test="wildcard-mask and (enable-wildcard-mask/text()='true')">
            <xsl:choose>
                <xsl:when test="(wildcard-mask/text()='255.255.255.255')"><netmask type="string">0.0.0.0</netmask></xsl:when>
                <xsl:when test="(wildcard-mask/text()='127.255.255.255')"><netmask type="string">128.0.0.0</netmask></xsl:when>
                <xsl:when test="(wildcard-mask/text()='63.255.255.255')"><netmask type="string">192.0.0.0</netmask></xsl:when>
                <xsl:when test="(wildcard-mask/text()='31.255.255.255')"><netmask type="string">224.0.0.0</netmask></xsl:when>
                <xsl:when test="(wildcard-mask/text()='15.255.255.255')"><netmask type="string">240.0.0.0</netmask></xsl:when>
                <xsl:when test="(wildcard-mask/text()='7.255.255.255')"><netmask type="string">248.0.0.0</netmask></xsl:when>
                <xsl:when test="(wildcard-mask/text()='3.255.255.255')"><netmask type="string">252.0.0.0</netmask></xsl:when>
                <xsl:when test="(wildcard-mask/text()='1.255.255.255')"><netmask type="string">254.0.0.0</netmask></xsl:when>
                <xsl:when test="(wildcard-mask/text()='0.255.255.255')"><netmask type="string">255.0.0.0</netmask></xsl:when>

                <xsl:when test="(wildcard-mask/text()='0.255.255.255')"><netmask type="string">255.0.0.0</netmask></xsl:when>
                <xsl:when test="(wildcard-mask/text()='0.127.255.255')"><netmask type="string">255.128.0.0</netmask></xsl:when>
                <xsl:when test="(wildcard-mask/text()='0.63.255.255')"><netmask type="string">255.192.0.0</netmask></xsl:when>
                <xsl:when test="(wildcard-mask/text()='0.31.255.255')"><netmask type="string">255.224.0.0</netmask></xsl:when>
                <xsl:when test="(wildcard-mask/text()='0.15.255.255')"><netmask type="string">255.240.0.0</netmask></xsl:when>
                <xsl:when test="(wildcard-mask/text()='0.7.255.255')"><netmask type="string">255.248.0.0</netmask></xsl:when>
                <xsl:when test="(wildcard-mask/text()='0.3.255.255')"><netmask type="string">255.252.0.0</netmask></xsl:when>
                <xsl:when test="(wildcard-mask/text()='0.1.255.255')"><netmask type="string">255.254.0.0</netmask></xsl:when>

                <xsl:when test="(wildcard-mask/text()='0.0.255.255')"><netmask type="string">255.255.0.0</netmask></xsl:when>
                <xsl:when test="(wildcard-mask/text()='0.0.127.255')"><netmask type="string">255.255.128.0</netmask></xsl:when>
                <xsl:when test="(wildcard-mask/text()='0.0.63.255')"><netmask type="string">255.255.192.0</netmask></xsl:when>
                <xsl:when test="(wildcard-mask/text()='0.0.31.255')"><netmask type="string">255.255.224.0</netmask></xsl:when>
                <xsl:when test="(wildcard-mask/text()='0.0.15.255')"><netmask type="string">255.255.240.0</netmask></xsl:when>
                <xsl:when test="(wildcard-mask/text()='0.0.7.255')"><netmask type="string">255.255.248.0</netmask></xsl:when>
                <xsl:when test="(wildcard-mask/text()='0.0.3.255')"><netmask type="string">255.255.252.0</netmask></xsl:when>
                <xsl:when test="(wildcard-mask/text()='0.0.1.255')"><netmask type="string">255.255.254.0</netmask></xsl:when>

                <xsl:when test="(wildcard-mask/text()='0.0.0.255')"><netmask type="string">255.255.255.0</netmask></xsl:when>
                <xsl:when test="(wildcard-mask/text()='0.0.0.127')"><netmask type="string">255.255.255.128</netmask></xsl:when>
                <xsl:when test="(wildcard-mask/text()='0.0.0.63')"><netmask type="string">255.255.255.192</netmask></xsl:when>
                <xsl:when test="(wildcard-mask/text()='0.0.0.31')"><netmask type="string">255.255.255.224</netmask></xsl:when>
                <xsl:when test="(wildcard-mask/text()='0.0.0.15')"><netmask type="string">255.255.255.240</netmask></xsl:when>
                <xsl:when test="(wildcard-mask/text()='0.0.0.7')"><netmask type="string">255.255.255.248</netmask></xsl:when>
                <xsl:when test="(wildcard-mask/text()='0.0.0.3')"><netmask type="string">255.255.255.252</netmask></xsl:when>
                <xsl:when test="(wildcard-mask/text()='0.0.0.1')"><netmask type="string">255.255.255.254</netmask></xsl:when>
                <xsl:when test="(wildcard-mask/text()='0.0.0.0')"><netmask type="string">255.255.255.255</netmask></xsl:when>
                <xsl:otherwise></xsl:otherwise>
            </xsl:choose>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:when test="netmask">
            <xsl:choose>
                <xsl:when test="(netmask/text()='0')"><netmask type="string">0.0.0.0</netmask></xsl:when>
                <xsl:when test="(netmask/text()='1')"><netmask type="string">128.0.0.0</netmask></xsl:when>
                <xsl:when test="(netmask/text()='2')"><netmask type="string">192.0.0.0</netmask></xsl:when>
                <xsl:when test="(netmask/text()='3')"><netmask type="string">224.0.0.0</netmask></xsl:when>
                <xsl:when test="(netmask/text()='4')"><netmask type="string">240.0.0.0</netmask></xsl:when>
                <xsl:when test="(netmask/text()='5')"><netmask type="string">248.0.0.0</netmask></xsl:when>
                <xsl:when test="(netmask/text()='6')"><netmask type="string">252.0.0.0</netmask></xsl:when>
                <xsl:when test="(netmask/text()='7')"><netmask type="string">254.0.0.0</netmask></xsl:when>
                <xsl:when test="(netmask/text()='8')"><netmask type="string">255.0.0.0</netmask></xsl:when>

                <xsl:when test="(netmask/text()='9')"><netmask type="string">255.128.0.0</netmask></xsl:when>
                <xsl:when test="(netmask/text()='10')"><netmask type="string">255.192.0.0</netmask></xsl:when>
                <xsl:when test="(netmask/text()='11')"><netmask type="string">255.224.0.0</netmask></xsl:when>
                <xsl:when test="(netmask/text()='12')"><netmask type="string">255.240.0.0</netmask></xsl:when>
                <xsl:when test="(netmask/text()='13')"><netmask type="string">255.248.0.0</netmask></xsl:when>
                <xsl:when test="(netmask/text()='14')"><netmask type="string">255.252.0.0</netmask></xsl:when>
                <xsl:when test="(netmask/text()='15')"><netmask type="string">255.254.0.0</netmask></xsl:when>

                <xsl:when test="(netmask/text()='16')"><netmask type="string">255.255.0.0</netmask></xsl:when>
                <xsl:when test="(netmask/text()='17')"><netmask type="string">255.255.128.0</netmask></xsl:when>
                <xsl:when test="(netmask/text()='18')"><netmask type="string">255.255.192.0</netmask></xsl:when>
                <xsl:when test="(netmask/text()='19')"><netmask type="string">255.255.224.0</netmask></xsl:when>
                <xsl:when test="(netmask/text()='20')"><netmask type="string">255.255.240.0</netmask></xsl:when>
                <xsl:when test="(netmask/text()='21')"><netmask type="string">255.255.248.0</netmask></xsl:when>
                <xsl:when test="(netmask/text()='22')"><netmask type="string">255.255.252.0</netmask></xsl:when>
                <xsl:when test="(netmask/text()='23')"><netmask type="string">255.255.254.0</netmask></xsl:when>

                <xsl:when test="(netmask/text()='24')"><netmask type="string">255.255.255.0</netmask></xsl:when>
                <xsl:when test="(netmask/text()='25')"><netmask type="string">255.255.255.128</netmask></xsl:when>
                <xsl:when test="(netmask/text()='26')"><netmask type="string">255.255.255.192</netmask></xsl:when>
                <xsl:when test="(netmask/text()='27')"><netmask type="string">255.255.255.224</netmask></xsl:when>
                <xsl:when test="(netmask/text()='28')"><netmask type="string">255.255.255.240</netmask></xsl:when>
                <xsl:when test="(netmask/text()='29')"><netmask type="string">255.255.255.248</netmask></xsl:when>
                <xsl:when test="(netmask/text()='30')"><netmask type="string">255.255.255.252</netmask></xsl:when>
                <xsl:when test="(netmask/text()='31')"><netmask type="string">255.255.255.254</netmask></xsl:when>
                <xsl:when test="(netmask/text()='32')"><netmask type="string">255.255.255.255</netmask></xsl:when>
                <xsl:otherwise></xsl:otherwise>
            </xsl:choose>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```